# Navigation Bar top item Title align left

Tags: ios, swift

How can i my title align left?

I want to title next to hamburger button.

Thanks for advices

[image: Navigation bar]

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "XXX"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

```
        let leftInsect = 30
        let leftLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - leftInsect, height: view.frame.height))
        leftLabel.text = "  XXX"
        leftLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        leftLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21)
        navigationItem.titleView = leftLabel
```

Adjust `leftInsect` according your need